# Cycle between keyword & user defined completion with C-N

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion

I use the following mapping to initiate keyword completion, followed by user defined completion:

```
inoremap <expr> <c-n> pumvisible() ? "\<c-x>\<c-o>" : "\<c-n>"
```

How can I rewrite this mapping so that repeatedly pressing `<c-n>` results in the cycling of keyword and user defined completion?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure when exactly you would initiate the cycling (as you typically use `<C-N>` to both trigger and go through the list of matches), but the key to implementing this is via a boolean flag stored in a variable. To be able to use `:let` to toggle this, you need to move from an inline expression to a function (which still returns the chosen completion key).

```
inoremap <expr> <c-n> TriggerOrToggleCompletion()
function! TriggerOrToggleCompletion()
    ...
endfunction
```

Comment: I use `<c-j>` and `<c-k>` when `pumvisble()` to move through the list. I will look in to this, thank you.